# expect: match_max setting buffer size incorrectly

Tags: tcl, expect

According to the *expect* manual page,

```
match_max
      defines the size of the buffer (in bytes) used internally by expect.
```

However, when I call `match_max` with value 1, *expect* internally works with four characters at a time. (This can be seen in the output generated by `exp_internal 1`.) Setting `match_max` to 2 makes *expect* use a buffer of seven bytes, 3 defines a buffer of ten chars, 4 leads to 13, and 5 to 16.

Why is this so?

**EDIT - answer to the question in the comment:**

Starting a telnet session manually gives this output:

```
Trying 192.168.xxx.yyy...
Connected to 192.168.xxx.yyy.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Running telnet with *expect*, `match_max` set to 1:

```
expect: does "Tryi" (spawn_id exp11) match glob pattern "Login: $"? no
"Password: $"? no
...
expect: does "ryin" (spawn_id exp11) match glob pattern "Login: $"? no
"Password: $"? no
```

Four characters were considered at a time.

Doing the same with `match_max 2`:

```
expect: does "Trying " (spawn_id exp11) match glob pattern "Login: $"? no
"Password: $"? no 
...
expect: does "ying 19" (spawn_id exp11) match glob pattern "Login: $"? no
"Password: $"? no
```

The buffer was actually set to seven chars.

Comment: Can you post the output which indicated the real `match_max` value? And what's the point of using so small buffer size?

Comment: The point of using so small buffer was to test if my `full_buffer` handler worked correctly.

Comment: No idea why. But if `match_max 1` really works then it would never match *long* patterns like `Login: $`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did a test. For small numbers (approximately less than `170`) `match_max N` actually means `3N + 1`. And for big numbers `N` means *a bit more than* `2N`. Seems like `expect` is using a very interesting algorithm. :)

```
$ cat foo.exp
log_user 0
spawn yes hello world
match_max [lindex $argv 0]
set n 0
expect {
    full_buffer {
        send_user "forgotten: [string length $expect_out(buffer)]\n"
        if { [incr n] < 5 } {
            exp_continue
        }
    }
}
$ expect foo.exp 1
forgotten: 4
forgotten: 4
forgotten: 4
forgotten: 4
forgotten: 4
$ expect foo.exp 10
forgotten: 31
forgotten: 31
forgotten: 31
forgotten: 31
forgotten: 31
$ expect foo.exp 100
forgotten: 206
forgotten: 301
forgotten: 301
forgotten: 301
forgotten: 301
$ expect foo.exp 1000
forgotten: 2085
forgotten: 2075
forgotten: 2085
forgotten: 2106
forgotten: 2099
$ expect foo.exp 10000
forgotten: 20220
forgotten: 20169
forgotten: 20436
forgotten: 20566
forgotten: 20326
$ expect foo.exp 100000
forgotten: 200133
forgotten: 200161
forgotten: 200408
forgotten: 200090
forgotten: 200440
$
```

#### UPDATE:

Only found this in `expect`'s source code ([`exp_clib.c`](http://expect.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/expect/expect/exp_clib.c?view=markup)):

```
/* get the latest buffer size.  Double the user input for two */
/* reasons.  1) Need twice the space in case the match */
/* straddles two bufferfuls, 2) easier to hack the division by */
/* two when shifting the buffers later on */

bufsiz = 2*exp_match_max;
```